# Filtering an array based on multiple arrays inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, filter, duplicates

I have three arrays.
1. Existing viewers array - `existingViewers`

2. New viewers array - `newViewers`
3. Permitted Viewers array - `permittedViewers`

`permittedViewers` is used for rendering the drop-down. And I wish to filter the `newViewers` and `existingViewers` entries from the `permittedViewers`.

I am doing this as three steps. And I am afraid this is not the optimized way. Can someone suggest the ideal way of doing this?
The expected result is

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "name5"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "name6"
  }
]
```

```js
let existingViewers = [{
      "viewerId": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "viewerId": 2,
      "name": "name2"
    }
  ],
  newViewers = [

    {
      "viewerId": 3,
      "name": "name3"
    }
  ],
  permittedViewers = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "name3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "name4"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "name5"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "name6"
    }
  ]
let grouped = [...existingViewers, ...newViewers]

let viewerFilter = grouped.map(viewer => { return viewer.viewerId; });

let filteredPermittedViewers = permittedViewers.filter(viewer => !viewerFilter.includes(viewer.id));

console.log(filteredPermittedViewers)
```

Comment: it looks like a *codereview* question, because the code is working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the Code Review SE site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a `Set` of the `id`s of the first two arrays, and then filter the third by whether the set includes the id. (`Set`s have `O(1)` lookup time)

```js
let existingViewers=[{"viewerId":1,"name":"name1"},{"viewerId":2,"name":"name2"}],newViewers=[{"viewerId":3,"name":"name3"}],permittedViewers=[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"},{"id":3,"name":"name3"},{"id":4,"name":"name4"},{"id":5,"name":"name5"},{"id":6,"name":"name6"}];

const ids = new Set([...existingViewers, ...newViewers].map(({ viewerId }) => viewerId));
const output = permittedViewers.filter(({ id }) => !ids.has(id));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That will require constructing a new `Set` every single time an item is tested - better to construct the set in advance. For compactness, use a minifier

Answer (score 2):

You can compress all three statements into a single statement -- just replace the variable name with the statement that creates it:

```js
let existingViewers = [{
      "viewerId": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "viewerId": 2,
      "name": "name2"
    }
  ],
  newViewers = [

    {
      "viewerId": 3,
      "name": "name3"
    }
  ],
  permittedViewers = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "name3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "name4"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "name5"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "name6"
    }
  ]

let filteredPermittedViewers = permittedViewers.filter(viewer => ! [...existingViewers, ...newViewers].map(viewer => viewer.viewerId).includes(viewer.id));

console.log(filteredPermittedViewers)
```